# 'Add to Bag / Basket' on category landing pages?

Tags: e-commerce, lists, shopping-cart

How I have the list currently displayed][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gfn0.jpg)I'm currently working on a site selling books and my client has asked where the 'Buy Book' buttons are. On the books listings (category) page do I need a call to action to add to bag? or 'buy book'? I would imagine users are likely to want to go to the product page and find out more about the book before adding it to their bag?

With that said, do I even need a 'About this book', 'More information' call to action when I could just click the title of the book?

I was looking for some research to back to hopefully suggest that these buttons are not needed. I've noticed eBay, Amazon, John Lewis etc. do not have big c2a's on their sites but does anyone have evidence as to why they are not necessary? Is it intuitive enough to click the title?

Thanks in advance!

[image: How I have displayed the book list currently]

Comment: Can you add a sketch of your idea?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the title is commonplace to see more information on an item.  You should however **allow selecting the title or the image** of the item, as this too has become commonplace and many people will do that.

In addition, making both the title and the image selectable also makes it easier to use on **mobile** devices as you are increasing the selectable area.

I am not aware of any research papers on this, but I do know that Amazon test everything thoroughly when it comes to anything that can affect purchase rates.  If they find it works, it's a safe bet to copy them.

---

As a side note, it took me a while to work out what you meant by referring to a 'bag'.  **Call it a basket** or shopping cart, and it will be much clearer.

Comment: By "selecting", do you mean clicking or am I just confused?

Comment: 'Selecting' is a generic term that covers both clicking and tapping.  'Clicking' is specific to a PC and excludes touch devices.